# Разбитие строк файла на несколько переменных

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть файл .txt файл, пример:

```
87933 2452 111
444 222 881
1248 218947 1298
```

Мне нужно, чтобы разбить строки по переменным

```
a, b, c=87933, 2452, 111
```

и дальше выполнить какой-то алгоритм, к примеру

```
if a>b and b>c:
    d=b
```

А потом сделать тоже самое для всех строк файла, вопрос: как присвоить значения переменным из строк файла

Answer (score 2):

1. считываете строку
2. разбиваете ее на слова через разделитель пробел
3. слова переводите в числа
4. числа присваиваете переменным

   ```
    text = "87933 2452 111"

    a, b, c = map(int, text.split())
   ```

строки из файла можно считать через `readlines`:

```
fin = open(<имя файла>, 'r', encoding='utf-8')
lines = fin.readlines()

for text in lines:
    # тут код работы с каждой строкой
fin.close()
```

Comment: мне нужно именно разбить строку, а не получить

Comment: @vanerk, split() разбивает строку - разве приведенный код вначале не делает то, что вам нужно и что вы написали в вопросе?

Answer (score 1):

Если совсем просто для понимания, то можно так:

```
with open("test.txt", "r") as file:
    for line in file: # Читаем файл построчно
        data = line.split() # Пребразуем значения в список
        a = data[0] # Присваиваем значение первого элемента списка
        b = data[1] # Присваиваем значение второго элемента списка
        c = data[2] # Присваиваем значение третьего элемента списка
        d = int(b) + 34 # Чего-нибудь делаем с данными
        print(f"Значение d = {d}") # Выводим полученные значения
```